# Any way to auto-format SQL in Stack Exchange Data Explorer?

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, code-formatting, sql

One really nice feature of Toad (database administration tool) is the ability to auto-format your SQL (usually with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>).

Manually formatting SQL greatly increases readability, but takes a lot of time (e.g., modifying the layout of SQL, adding or removing extra whitespace, adding or removing extra lines, changing the case for keywords, indenting blocks, etc.)

Does the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) have any kind of auto-formatting feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no such feature in the Data Explorer, at least not one that is documented in the [help page](https://data.stackexchange.com/help).

Having said that, it's indeed a great [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), and let's hope the SE devs pick up on it!

**EDIT:**
As @animuson pointed out, since the Data Explorer is [open source](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer), anyone could file a PR to implement this feature.

Comment: SEDE is actually open source software not completely made by us. Anyone could add the feature. ;)

Comment: @animuson someone at SE will still need to deploy the updated version to https://data.stackexchange.com/, but you're right, singling out "SE devs" as I did is probably wrong.

Comment: [Nick will merge and deploy at irregular intervals](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pulls?q=is%3Apr+is%3Aclosed)